# Can I run a Puppeteer.js scraper on a Windows Server without docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, web-scraping, windows-server-2003, puppeteer

I have absolutely no experience using docker, but I'm trying to build a robust website scraper using Puppeteer.

Can I run it in a Windows Server 2003 environment running SQL Server 2008 R2 without having to go back and keep tweaking it later?

If yes, then how? Just as I would in a normal Node environment (i.e. NPM)?

Answer (score 0):

I personally have no experience running puppeteer on windows, but I think you can do it connecting to a "remote instance of chromium" (in the same machine), the "browser" that launched puppeteer, this is the thing that have problems working in windows.

You can follow this examples to make this connection.

https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2017/10/04/browser-automation-with-puppeteer/

https://blog.rnsloan.com/2017/10/27/puppeteer-windows/

Let me know if this works.